# pl/sql: You have an error in your SQL syntax how to fix this error?

Tags: plsql

I am creating a new procedure and I got an error :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax

How to fix this error ? Is there a problem of quotes ?

```
  delimiter //
  MariaDB [assign5]> create procedure doissuebook(p1 int ,p2    
  varchar(20),p3 varchar(20),p4 varchar(30))
-> X: Begin
-> set @p3val=str_to_date(p3,'%d/%m/%y');
-> set @p5val="I";
-> --Exception handling
-> set @errormsg='';
-> if p1 <=0 then
-> begin
->          set @errormsg='Wrong roll number specified';
->          select @errormsg;
->          leave X;
-> end;
-> end if;
-> if length(p4) <=0 then
-> begin
->          set @errormsg='Wrong book specified';
->          select @errormsg;
->          leave X;
-> end;
-> end if;
-> insert into borrower (roll_no,name,DateOfIssue,NameOfBook,status)  
values (p1,p2,@p3val,p4,@p5val);
-> END
-> //
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>       that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to
>       use near '--Exception handling
>       set @errormsg='';
>       if p1 <=0 then
>       begin
>                   set @errormsg='Wro' at line 5

Answer (score 1):

The line `--Exception handling` is a comment. [MariaDB requires a space after the two dashes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/comment-syntax/) , so change to `-- Exception handling`.